# Workflow 2013 http request with credentials

Tags: workflow, credentials, cors

I have a `C#` `WebApi2` endpoint with `CORS` and `SupportsCredentials` activated. What I'm trying to do is to call this endpoint from a Workflow. How do I pass the credentials?